# THREE.InstancedBufferGeometry, THREE.MultiMaterial and groups

Tags: three.js, buffer-geometry

I need some clarification regarding the use of `addGroup` method in `THREE.InstancedBufferGeometry`, when using it with `THREE.MultiMaterial`.

This is r75, source looks like this:

```
THREE.InstancedBufferGeometry.prototype.addGroup = function ( start, count, instances ) {
    this.groups.push( {
        start: start,
        count: count,
        instances: instances
    } );
};
```

I see no other use of field "instances" besides the "copy" method. There is no "materialIndex" field on this groups like in `THREE.BufferGeometry`.

If I try to render something like **`Mesh( InstancedBufferGeometry, MultiMaterial )`** does not work, I get an error from "visible" field in group material.

Replacing `instances` with `materialIndex` in `addGroup` works just fine, but must be another use intended for `instances` field. I'm not understanding this, or maybe this is a bug.

Post in three.js page: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/8912

Comment: Good question. Do you mind posting on the three.js site?

Comment: Can you provide a link in your question if you posted in on the three.js page? Might be useful to others.

Comment: @Wilt - [github discussion link](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/8912).

Comment: Fix merged to the latest dev branch [#9815](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/9815).